# ¿Cómo recortar una imagen usando OpenCV en C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

He hecho un programa que me recorta una imagen, pero el recorte se realiza pre-definido, es decir, en el código se especifica las dimensiones del rectángulo qué se recorta, y yo lo que necesito es que una vez que se abra la imagen poder seleccionar en ella la parte que quiero recortar.

Este es mi código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe como podría hacerlo... muchas gracias!

Comment: si copias y pegas el código, la calidad de tu pregunta aumetará, la razón: quien quiera ayudarte, le será más fácil copiar y pegar :D Te invito a darte una vuelta por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas cómo funciona el sitio :D saludos

Answer (score 1):

> UPDATE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> //Compruebe que en su SO el include es asi


using namespace std;

//Para controlar los click del raton
bool click = false;

//Puntos
cv::Point P1(0,0);
cv::Point P2(0,0);

cv::Rect recorte_rect(0,0,0,0);

//Para las imagenes
cv::Mat img, img_t;

void actualizar_imagen(){

  img_t = img.clone();

  cv::rectangle(img_t, recorte_rect, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0));

  cv::imshow("imagen_original", img_t);

  //evitar errores cuando no se cumple
  if(recorte_rect.width > 0 && recorte_rect.height>0){
    cv::imshow("imagen_recortada",img_t(recorte_rect));
  }
}
//Usamos este call para manejar los eventos del raton
void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata){

     if  ( event == cv::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN ){

          cout << "button izquierdo pulsando - posicion ( " << x << ", " << y << " )" << endl;

            click = true;

          //añadimos los valores de las posiciones a los puntos P1 y P2
          P1.x = x;
          P1.y = y;

          P2.x = x;
          P2.y = y;
     }

     if ( event == cv::EVENT_LBUTTONUP ){

          //temp_inico
          P1.x = x;
          P1.y = y;
          //temp_fin

            P2.x=x;
          P2.y=y;

          click = false;
     }else if  ( event == cv::EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN ){
          cout << "button derecho pulsando - posicion ( " << x << ", " << y << " )" << endl;        
     }else if  ( event == cv::EVENT_MBUTTONDOWN ){
          cout << "button central pulsando - posicion ( " << x << ", " << y << " )" << endl;
     }else if ( event == cv::EVENT_MOUSEMOVE ){
          cout << "Desplazaminto del raton - posicion ( " << x << ", " << y << " )" << endl;

          //if(click){ alternativa a if(click == true){ -> me gusta usarlo entre otras cosas por si se te olvida un '=' 
            if(click){

                P2.x = x;
                P2.y = y;
            }
    }

//calculos para determinar el Rect ect.
    if(click){

         if(P1.x > P2.x){ 

            recorte_rect.x = P2.x;
            recorte_rect.width = P1.x - P2.x; 

         }else { 

            recorte_rect.x = P1.x;
            recorte_rect.width = P2.x - P1.x;
          }

        if(P1.y > P2.y){ 

          recorte_rect.y = P2.y;
          recorte_rect.height = P1.y - P2.y;

        }else {  

          recorte_rect.y = P1.y;
          recorte_rect.height = P2.y-P1.y; 
        }

    }


actualizar_imagen();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){

  // Como ya sabe leemos la imagen -> ajuste si ruta 
  img = cv::imread("nombre_imagen.jpg");

  //Comprobamos
  if (img.empty()) { 

    cout << "Error al cargar la imagen - compruebe la ruta asignada o que la imagen se encuentra en la ruta" << endl;

  return -1; 
  }

  //Creamos la ventanita
  cv::namedWindow("imagen_original", 1);

  //Hacemos el set del la funcion callback que creamos para manejar los eventos del raton
  cv::setMouseCallback("imagen_original", CallBackFunc, NULL);

  //Mostramos la imagen
  cv::imshow("imagen_original", img);

  cv::waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

> ANTIGUO:

*...pero el recorte se realiza pre-definido...y yo lo que necesito es que una vez que se abra la imagen poder seleccionar en ella la parte que quiero recortar.*

Pseudocode

`Rect myROI(10, 10, 100, 100);` me imagino que esta linea es la encarda de determinar el recorte en la imagen, de ser asi lo que usted necesita es poder pasarle los valores que desea los cuales corresponderian a las dimenciones,

Ahora segun entiendo *...se abra la imagen poder seleccionar en ella...* usted necesita crear una interface grafica, para poder determinar las dimenciones me imagino que busca un comportamiento similar al de un editor de fotos en el cual seleccionas con un cuadrado o similar y recortas, para ello lo comentado tiene que crear la interface, puede usar muchas librerias para este fin por citar alguna `Qt`

Cuando tenga la UI, podria crear un metodo con el codigo para recortar la imagen algo asi

```
mi_metodo(a, b, c, d){
//..
   Rect myROI(a, b, c, d);
//..
}
```

y este ser llamado desde la UI pasandole los datos que usted quiera.

Pero si lo que quiere es hacerlo desde la consola en principio es igual que lo anterior pero solo tendria que leer los datos de entrada que el usuario ingrese y pasarlos al "metodo", aunque creo que lo que usted busca es usando una UI grafica.

P.D: No se lo deje como comentario pues es muy largo, ademas intente en la medida de lo posible poner el codigo en formato texto y no en imagen pues es mucho mas comodo para trabajar y de ser necesario copiarlo para ralizar pruebas. Saludos

Comment: Vale, voy a intentar hacerlo usando una librería adicional, empezaré por la que me ha dicho a ver si lo consigo, muchas gracias!

Comment: @JessicaGarreMorales despues de leer su comentario, volvi a leer su pregunta, y creo que quizas yo le respondi con un enfoque diferente, mas pensando en crear un programa centrado en la edicion, tengo un codigo sin usar ninguna libreria que quizas es lo que busca lo acabo de "terminar" solo faltan algunos detalles, si me comenta en esta respuesta entendere que esta por aqui y lo publicare lo antes que pueda, si no me comenta lo subire igual pero me lo tomare con calma. P.D: Antes de enfrascarse en el uso de Qt, espere a que publique el codigo.Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, si lo sube me haría un gran favor porque no conseguí hacerlo investigando otras librerías! Saludos

Comment: Ah por lo que veo ya lo ha subido! Muchas gracias de nuevo!